# How to deal with "iterative development by Stack Overflow spam"?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

I have noticed a couple of times OPs who ask a series of questions, each one of which may have (albeit dubious) merit, but which overall are an attempt to develop software by asking a question for every tiny step of the process. How can this best be dealt with?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is nothing to deal with. Each question should be considered on its own. Someone wants to know how to open a file, or better why they get a particular error message when they try to open a file like this [sample code]? Great. They find out their problem. The next day they want to know how to read a line of text, or better why this attempt to read a line of text gets a compiler error? Still great. As long as each question is on topic, is answerable, is of use to other people, and is not a duplicate, it's fine.

There is some [rate limiting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide), so if you're worried that they are asking a question an hour and somehow drowning out other askers or consuming too much volunteer time, that has been taken care of. Other than that, you do best when you don't pay attention to who is asking the question or what they asked before. Questions and answers, that's the focus.

Comment: Of course, being a thousandfold duplicate is a grounds for downvoting, and "why doesn't this compile" is  "close-as-typo"-worthy in 99% cases.